# patch configuration based on the Role

Tags: sitecore-client

We have a custom session state applied only on the `content delivery` server. so we created a patch configuration for web.config.xdt and included that line

```
<system.web >
        
        <sessionState xdt:Transform="Replace" mode="Custom" cookieless="false" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="20"
     sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager, Sitecore.Kernel" customProvider="redis">
            <providers>
                <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard"
                  connectionStringName="session" pollingEnabled="true" pollingInterval="60" pollingMaxExpiredSessionsPerSecond="0" pollingMaxInstances="1"
                  compression="true"/>
                <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private"
                  connectionString="redis.sessions" pollingInterval="60" compression="true"/>
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
```

But this line should work on CD only not for CM.

How to add this config only for Content Delivery.

I had tried below method but this shows error

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"  xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <system.web >
            
            <sessionState role:require="ContentDelivery"  xdt:Transform="Replace" mode="Custom" cookieless="false" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="20"
         sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager, Sitecore.Kernel" customProvider="redis">
                <providers>
                    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard"
                      connectionStringName="session" pollingEnabled="true" pollingInterval="60" pollingMaxExpiredSessionsPerSecond="0" pollingMaxInstances="1"
                      compression="true"/>
                    <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private"
                      connectionString="redis.sessions" pollingInterval="60" compression="true"/>
                </providers>
            </sessionState>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

XDT is just an XML file with a set of rules of what and how to transform within `web.comfig`. We may use them in cases when we need to somehow transform `web.config` outside of `<sitecore>` node of configuration so that we can't rely on config paths that only apply within the `<sitecore>` node. XDT structure corresponds to the structure of target web.config file with additional commands coming from XML-Document-Transform XML namespace.

Configuration transform relies on `msbuild` to do this job. But instead of Debug, Release or Clean targets, it uses a target called `ApplyTransform` It accepts numerous parameters, among those we have `XDT` file to transform, target folder, target configuration file to be transformed and few other parameters.

Using this xdt file sets up the `web.config` for CD servers, regular web.config file is set up for CM servers.
Applying transform through VSTS using XDT Transform task before CD App Service install.

So in your `Web.CD.config` you need to replace the config.

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"  xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <system.web >
            <sessionState  xdt:Transform="Replace" mode="Custom" cookieless="false" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="20"
         sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager, Sitecore.Kernel" customProvider="redis">
                <providers>
                    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard"
                      connectionStringName="session" pollingEnabled="true" pollingInterval="60" pollingMaxExpiredSessionsPerSecond="0" pollingMaxInstances="1"
                      compression="true"/>
                    <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private"
                      connectionString="redis.sessions" pollingInterval="60" compression="true"/>
                </providers>
            </sessionState>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Refer to these links for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/applying-configuration-transforms.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [role based configuration](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-rule-based-configuration.html) that you are referring to in your question is specifically for Sitecore configuration patch files, which you should use to apply changes to the settings in Sitecore.config file.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"  xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentManagement">
    <commands>
        ... some command ...
    </commands>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This approach cannot be used control which settings are applied within the web.config file. Instead you must perform a web transform during your deployment.

An example of this might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState xdt:Locator="Match(sessionIDManagerType)" xdt:Transform="Replace" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager, Sitecore.Kernel" mode="Custom" cookieless="false" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="20"  customProvider="redis">
            <providers>
                <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard"
                  connectionStringName="session" pollingEnabled="true" pollingInterval="60" pollingMaxExpiredSessionsPerSecond="0" pollingMaxInstances="1"
                  compression="true"/>
                <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private"
                  connectionString="redis.sessions" pollingInterval="60" compression="true"/>
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only patch and apply role based transformation on Sitecore related configuration. `Sytem.web` is `asp.net` configuration tag. It's not possible to do that on them.